# AWK command not working properly for NF

Tags: awk, command

I am using the following awk command to find all the records which are having exactly 34 columns separated by `^A` (special character) as delimiter. But even if all the records are having 34 columns some records are missing. I could not find the reason.

```
awk -F "\001" 'NF==34' sl_idms_fdc_consolidate > sl_idms_fdc_consolidate_temp
```

Comment: 100% the reason is that the records do NOT have 34 columns (fields). Check your input file again. If on UNIX try `cat -v` to see control chars. Try running `dos2unix` to remove any spurious control-Ms if your file was created on Windows.

Comment: A useful debugging command might be `awk -F "\001" '{print NF}'`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why @Ed Morton and @glenn jackman didn't answer the question directly, maybe it is too simple. I have time today, and I reply it.

`^A` can be typed by `ctrl+V+A`, but @Ed Morton's suggest can't help to fix this issue.

1) I try the command and get error when the file has ^A in it.

```
$ dos2unix file file
dos2unix: Binary symbol found at line 1
dos2unix: Skipping binary file file
dos2unix: Binary symbol found at line 1
dos2unix: Skipping binary file file
```

2) it doesn't change NF value

So I still prefer @glenn jackman's solution, check and print out the real NF to confirm if  your input file has 34 ^A or not.

```
awk -F "\001" '{print NF}' file

or

awk -F "^A" '{print NF}' file   # you need hold `control+V+A` at same time to type `^A`
```

3) when you need check the special characters, use below commands

```
cat -A file        # some systems may not support `-A` option
cat -vet file
```